# .htaccess 403 Forbidden exclusions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I am trying to make it so my 403 Forbidden page is on every page, except one.  The folder/directory I don't want 403 Forbidden to be on is called "download".

Here is my current .htaccess code.

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another `.htaccess` file in the downloads directory that cancels out the main one:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: Make sure to flag my answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem.